# sort same field from different tables

Tags: php, mysql, multi-table

I have somes tables (around 20) with the same structure and I'm trying to sort them with a php script and insert them in a new table with the cheapest price in cheapest1, then cheapest2 for more expensive...  and the most expensive in column cheapest20:

**table A:**
id
name
price

**table B:**
id
name
price

**table X:**
id
name
price

**tableResult:**
id
name
cheapest1
price1
cheapest2
price2
...
cheapestX
priceX

My code so far is:

```
(SELECT id, price, name FROM tableA WHERE id = $id)
UNION
(SELECT id, price, name FROM tableB WHERE id = $id)
ORDER BY price ASC
```

I have been looking for different solutions but it takes too long to SELECT for 15000 rows so I guess there is another way to do it.
I haven't looked for the update query yet, I need to fix the select in the first time.

Any suggestion?

EDIT: clarified question, with more tables

EDIT2: solution

I finally got it right. This is the query to select the cheapest:
I select each id and I browse:

```
(SELECT price AS P1, name, id FROM tableA WHERE id = ?) UNION (SELECT price AS P1, name, id FROM tableB WHERE id = ?) UNION (SELECT price AS P1, name, id FROM tableC WHERE id = ?) ORDER BY P1 ASC
```

Then I Insert in the new table as glglgl suggested:

```
('INSERT INTO table (id, name, Position, price) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have control over the final structure of the tables: Don't do that. Instead, use only one table and add a field for indicating which purpose it serves.

The target table is not structured well either. Instead, you should use

```
tableResult:
 id
 name
 cheapestorder
 cheapest
 price
```

which makes all easier.

Thus, instead of having one row containing

```
id=10, name=foo, cheapest1=a, cheapestprice1=10, cheapest2=b, cheapestprice2=13,
```

you have several rows

```
id=10, name=foo, cheapestorder=1, cheapest=a, cheapestprice=10
id=10, name=foo, cheapestorder=2, cheapest=b, cheapestprice=13
```

(This process is called **"normalization"** in database theory.)

Putting all input tables into one simplifies [dcp's query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10857607/296974):

```
SELECT name,
       max(mxprice) mxprice,
       min(mnprice) mnprice
FROM
(
  SELECT name,
       max(price) mxprice,
       min(price) mnprice
    FROM tableABC
    GROUP BY NAME, tbltag
) a
GROUP BY NAME
```

or maybe even just

```
SELECT name,
       max(price) mxprice,
       min(price) mnprice
    FROM tableABC
    GROUP BY NAME
```

.

Comment: Indeed, I can create the table I need, I have total control. What should cheapestorder contain? How do I get it? Because I need info about each "ranking" of each table for each row.

Comment: @glglgl - Nice job of stealing my query.

Comment: @dcp yes - but under changed preconditions.

Comment: @glglgl - It's bad sportsmanship and poor manners, especially since you didn't even bother upvoting the original answer you stole the query from. But whatever. If you are so dog-eat-dog about rep points, you can have them. Geez. I thought this community was about respect.

Comment: @dcp I think you didn't get the whole point about my answer: it was the point of normalization and aggregation of input and output tables which you didn't even think about.

Comment: @glglgl - The question was edited after I posted my answer, and I wasn't online when that happened. So you took the liberty of stealing my query, and then adjusting it to the edited question. And yes, I would have thought of normalization, but original question had only 2 tables in it. Had I had a chance to see the edited question, I could have revised my answer based on the edited question. But as I said, you can have the freaking rep points. What a jerk! It's people like you that make me want to just quit answering questions and helping people.

Comment: You seem to forget: It is not up to me which answer the OP accepts. So I can nothing do about the points. And if I take your query as a template and **improve it** - what is the problem? I even left you a courtesy, so what's up? I think it is time to calm down again.

Comment: @glglgl - Fair enough. as I said I don't care about the rep points, my main goal when I answer a question is to help someone solve a problem. I didn't see the reference to my query you added in your edited answer, so I appreciate that, and I'm fine with it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I did this on Oracle, but syntax should be very similar for MySQL (the select should work without any changes at all).

```
CREATE TABLE tableA (NAME VARCHAR2(100), price FLOAT);
CREATE TABLE tableB (NAME VARCHAR2(100), price FLOAT);

INSERT INTO tableA VALUES ('a',14.23);
INSERT INTO tableA VALUES ('b',15.23);
INSERT INTO tableA VALUES ('b',16.23);

INSERT INTO tableB VALUES ('a',12.23);
INSERT INTO tableB VALUES ('a',13.23);
INSERT INTO tableB VALUES ('b',9.23);

SELECT name
     , max(mxprice) mxprice
     , min(mnprice) mnprice
FROM
(
  SELECT name
       , max(price) mxprice
       , min(price) mnprice
    FROM tableA
    GROUP BY NAME
  UNION ALL
  SELECT name
       , max(price) mxprice
       , min(price) mnprice
    FROM tableB
    GROUP BY NAME
) a
GROUP BY NAME
```

Result:

```
    NAME    MXPRICE MNPRICE
1   a       14.23   12.23
2   b       16.23   9.23
```

Comment: That's exaclty what I want but this works only with 2 tables (min/max). I should have 20 tables at the end so my purpose was to order them from the cheapest to the most expensive for example.